# Pass array value to getStaticProps in Next js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm doing fetch request to get my Youtube playlist. and in doing so i used `getStaticProps()`, the problem I'm facing is that my playlist depends on my array of objects result.

```
export async function getStaticProps(){
  const MY_PLAYLIST = process.env.YOUTUBE_PLAYLIST_ID;
  const API_KEY = process.env.YOUTUBE_API_KEY;
  //const REQUEST_URL = `https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&playlistId=${MY_PLAYLIST}&key=${API_KEY}`;
  const REQUEST_URL = `https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channelSections?part=snippet&channelId=${MY_PLAYLIST}&key=${API_KEY}`;

  const response = await fetch(REQUEST_URL);
  const result = await response.json();

  return{
    props:{result: result},
    revalidate: 3600,
  }
}
```

the array of objects structure is in my `./utils/playlists.js` file.

```
const Playlist = [
  {
    id: 1,
    playlistId: '...first_playlist_id...',
    name: ' name '
  },
  {
    id: ,
    playlistId: '...second_playlist_id...',
    name: ' name '
  },
...
]

export default Playlist;
```

what i want to achieve is that instead of getting my `const MY_PLAYLIST = process.env.YOUTUBE_PLAYLIST_ID;` from my `.env.local` file to get it from `./utils.Playlist.js` file as `const MY_PLAYLIST = selected_playlist` . in regular situation i use

```
{Playlist.map((list, index)=>{
   return (
     <Card list={list} key={index}/>
   )
})}
```

to map my arrays of objects. so what should i do in my static props function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution with SWR**

Add a new folder called 'json' and add a new file called 'data.json' inside. Then paste your data like below (without assignment to a variable)

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    playlistId: '...first_playlist_id...',
    name: ' name '
  },
  {
    id: ,
    playlistId: '...second_playlist_id...',
    name: ' name '
  },
...
]
```

Add a new file inside your pages/api folder called 'fetch.js' and paste the code below

```
import path from 'path';
import { promises as fs } from 'fs';

export default async function handler(req, res) {
  const dataDirectory = path.join(process.cwd(), 'json');
  const fileContents = await fs.readFile(dataDirectory + '/data.json', 'utf8');

  res.status(200).json(fileContents);
}
```

Install the swr  library

```
npm install --save swr
```

Display the data using the swr library

```
import useSWR from 'swr';

const fetcher = (url) => fetch(url).then((res) => res.json());

export default function Index() {
  const { data, error } = useSWR('/api/fetch', fetcher);

  if (error) return <div>Error!</div>;
  if (!data) return <div>Loading..</div>;

  return (
    <div>
      {data.map((item, index) => <Card list={item} key={index} />)}
    </div>
  )
}
```